# Combining geojson and json for leaftlet

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I have a Leaflet map with a GeoJson Layer on it

```
    var objJson = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/salucci/Leaflet-Teste/master/BrasilNovo.json";
geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX(objJson, { style: style, 
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature});
    geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
    info.addTo(map);
```

And also have a Ajax request that receives Json data from a local PHP server.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1/projects/phpController.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {"Codigo": 1100023},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); //here is my data
    },
    error: function(error){
         console.log("Error:");
         console.log(error);
    }
});
```

The GeoJson is a kind of heavy, so I don't want to generate de whole GeoJson on server everytime, the Idea is merge the **static** GeoJson and the **dynamic** Json by ID(something like SQL join) after the Ajax request and then put the merged object on the Leaflet Layer

The GeoJson looks like:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-73,-7],[-73,-8]]]},"properties":{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","ID":"1"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-73,-7],[-73,-9]]]},"properties":{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","ID":"2"}},
{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-73,-7],[-73,-11]]]},"properties":{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","ID":"3"}}]}
```

And the Json from Ajax request looks like:

```
[{"id":"1","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"id":"2","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"},{"id":"3","field3":"value3","field4":"value4"}]
```

So Basically I want to put the fields field3 and field4 with their values into GeoJson properties joining by id. What's the best/fastest way to perform that using javascript?

Is there a way to merge another(third) Json later in runtime?

Comment: After receiving the dynamic json, loop through it. Check if the id is present in your GeoJson properties. If so, append it to the matching key? Otherwise, add it? If you put this in a function, like `merge(geoJson, json)` then you can merge other jsons too. Not hard to accomplish right?

Comment: It's possible, but how to check if the id is present in the GeoJson? I think I'll need to loop through it too, but where is the GeoJson object? maybe this is much more a "Leaflet question" instead of a "JS question"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Leaflet parses your GeoJSON data and builds a GeoJSON Layer Group (that you have stored in your `geojsonLayer` variable) out of it, it records the features data into the `feature`property of each corresponding layer.

So for instance, in your `geojsonLayer` you will get (among others) a polygon with: (below referred to as "`layer`")

```js
layer.feature.type // "Feature"
layer.feature.geometry // {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-73,-7],[-73,-8]]]}
layer.feature.properties // {"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","ID":"1"}
```

So for example you could do:

```js
geojsonLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  if (layer.feature.properties.ID === jsonObj.id) {
    for (var key in jsonObj) {
      layer.feature.properties[key] = jsonObj[key];
    }
  }
});
```

Of course you could then improve your algorithm to cache the references to your Leaflet layers, instead of having to loop through `geojsonLayer` every time.

Comment: thank you for your answer and time. What to you mean with cache the reference? I'll need a "faster" way to do that I think, cause the GeoJson will have over than 5 thousand features and loop through it doesn't seem like a good idea

Comment: Try first to get it working this way. You can improve it later. Feel free to ask a new question with your new code. As some people say: "it is easier to optimize a working code, than to get working an optimized code"...