# Return name of geoJSON leaflet layer with click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a leaflet map with multiple geoJSON layers:

```
var site1 = new L.geoJSON(site1_geojson, {
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, style);
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

I would like the `onEachFeature` function to return the name (e.g. "site1") of the layer clicked on. Something like:

```
var nameOfLayer;
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function(e) {
        nameOfLayer = ????
    });
}
```

I've tried assigning `feature` and `layer` to `nameOfLayer`, but from what I can gather those look like just the point clicked on, not the geoJSON layer itself.

Is this possible to do with leaflet and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constant string:

```js
var site1 = L.geoJSON(site1_geojson, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, style);
    }
}).addTo(map).bindPopup('Site 1');
```

If you want a popup specific to each layer / feature, and this specific content is reachable in each Feature properties, you can refer to [Combining geojson and json for leaftlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106015/combining-geojson-and-json-for-leaftlet/44108110#44108110) and [Leaflet omnivore + clustering markers + filtering marker cluster group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38702679/leaflet-omnivore-clustering-markers-filtering-marker-cluster-group/38709857#38709857)